# Не могу импортировать мувик в intellij idea

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, символы

муки перехода с FB. гружу прелоадер, строка:

```
preloader.progressBar.mask.x = -500 + procent / 100 * 500;
```

builder видит `preloader.progressBar` как `movie clip`, `idea` как `null`, поэтому ругается. трабл в настройках? где?

(swc импортирован, preloader виден как мувик, подозреваю настройки восприятия кадров flash'а)

Comment: Возможно у idea, как и у flashdevelop точка входа должна расширять Sprite?

Comment: @shatal вы предлагаете менять настройки мувика - я могу поменять весь прелоадер, могу остаться на flash builder'е. почему не работает в идее? где-то не хочет кушать кадры или импорт swc из flash ide...

Comment: Я бы попробовал изменить расширяемый прелодером класс на Sprite, если это возможно. Если не поможет, то я не знаю в чем проблема, никогда не использовал готовые прелодеры.

Comment: почему то ставлю в Base Class `preloader`: flash.display.Sprite и он после Ok и открытия опять остаётся пустым, но это ладно, оно - всёравно не то наверное, спсбо, @shatal. кто знает?